# Decompress TIFF-File

Tags: python, jpeg, tiff, geotiff, lzw

I have a Tiff-File (BigTiff, because it is ~8GB). Now I want to scale it down (4K Resolution) and I am struggling to find the correct software. When I find a software or lib which can handle Tiff-Files they have Problems with BigTiff, Dimesion (My file has a dimension > 65500 Pixels) or the LZW-Compression.

Can somebody give me a hint for a good software or lib which scales down
the Tiff-File or can convert it to a other File-Format? (Linux/Mac preferred)

Comment: ImageMagick can process BigTiff files. But you may have to modify your policy.xml file to permit the use of more RAM or map space. See https://imagemagick.org/source/policy.xml from https://imagemagick.org/script/resources.php. You also need to install bigtiff library for tiff, for example, see http://bigtiff.org

Comment: Thank you for this hint. It worked half the way. My command was `convert in.tiff -size 2048x2048 -out.jpg`. After a long time i got this error `convert: Maximum supported image dimension is 65500 pixels 'out-0.jpg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/340.` But now I got 10 Files like (out-0.jpg, out-1.jpg ...). What did I wrong?. `convert -list format` says I have `TIFF64* TIFF      rw-   Tagged Image File Format (64-bit) (LIBTIFF, Version 4.0.10)`

Comment: `convert in.tiff -size 2048x2048 -out.jpg`  is not a valid ImageMagick command. It should be `convert in.tiff out.jpg` or if you want to change the size, then `convert in.tiff -resize 2048x2048 out.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the software I use is "convert" from ImageMagick.
It is standard software in Ubuntu and it's completely command line.

To use it:

```
convert file1.tiff file2.jpg
```

Clearly, there are many other options you can use.  The only problem
is that I am not sure if it can deal with 8 gb files.